# Slide selected verticles along an edge

Tags: modeling

I am trying to move a selected portion of my model along an edge which is not parallel to any of the axis. I have to do this multiple times and I was wondering if there is a smart way of doing it.
Green is the edge on which I want to move the selected vertices up in the arrow direction .

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could temporarily extrude the edge, define the face's normal as custom orientation and move along one axis in this custom orientation? https://i.imgur.com/CNwlW6S.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady no need to extrude, just select side edge (marked by green) and press plus icon (in your screen) to define orientation and move vertices works.

Comment: How do I limit the movement to this edge once I added it as orientation?

Comment: @vklidu you're correct, makes perfect sense, since you want to move along the line, and not perpendicularly to it in another axis.

Comment: Ok I think I got it, if the orientation is the edge, I press twice Z to lock on the new Z axis, right?

Comment: Hm ... I would say it is along Y axis (pressed once along local orientation). Select "Move" tool so you can see axis orientation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select an edge you want to move along, then expand *Transform Orientations* combo-box and click on a **+** sign to add a new orientation. Now select the vertices you want to move and move them along green **Y** axis (<kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> shortcuts)

[image]